# Using String Masks in Perl

Tags: perl, masking

I have a program that allows a user to specify a mask such as MM-DD-YYYY, and compare it to a string. In the string, the *MM* will be assumed to be a month, *DD* will be the day of the month, and YYYY will be the year. Everything else must match exactly:

- String: 12/31/2010  Mask MM-DD-YYYY: Fail: Must use slashes and not dashes
- String: 12/31/2010  Mask DD/MM/YYYY: Fail: Month must be second and there's no month *31*.
- String: 12/31-11 Mask: MM/DD-YY: Pass: String matches mask.

Right now, I use `index` and `substr` to pull out the month, day, and year, then I use `xor` to generate a mask for everything else. It seems a bit inelegant, and I was wondering if there's a better way of doing this:

```
my $self = shift;
my $date = shift;

my $format = $self->Format();

my $month;
my $year;
my $day;

my $monthIndex;
my $yearIndex;
my $dayIndex;

#
# Pull out Month, Day, and Year
#
if (($monthIndex = index($format, "MM")) != -1) {
    $month = substr($date, $monthIndex, 2);
}

if (($dayIndex = index($format, "DD")) != -1) {
    $day = substr($date, $dayIndex, 2);
}

if (($yearIndex = index($format, "YYYY")) != -1) {
    $year = substr($date, $yearIndex, 4);
}
elsif (($yearIndex = index($format, "YY")) != -1) {
    $year = substr($date, $yearIndex, 2);
    if ($year < 50) {
        $year += 2000;
    }
    else {
        $year += 1900;
    }
}

#
# Validate the Rest of Format
#

(my $restOfFormat = $format) =~ s/[MDY]/./g;    #Month Day and Year can be anything
if ($date !~ /^$restOfFormat$/) {
    return; #Does not match format
}
[...More Stuff before I return a true value...]
```

I'm doing this for a date, time (using *HH*, *MM*, *SS*, and *A*/*AA*), and IP addresses in my code.

---

BTW, I tried using regular expressions to pull the date from the string, but it's even messier:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# FIND MONTH
#
    my $mask = "M" x length($format);  #All M's the length of format string

    my $monthMask = ($format ^ $mask);      #Bytes w/ "M" will be "NULL"
    $monthMask =~ s/\x00/\xFF/g;    #Change Null bytes to "FF"
    $monthMask =~ s/[^\xFF]/\x00/g; #Null out other bytes

    #
    #   ####Mask created! Apply mask to Date String
    #

    $month = ($monthMask & $date);  #Nulls or Month Value
    $month =~ s/\x00//g;            #Remove Null bytes from string
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It's a neat programming trick, but it was pretty hard to understand exactly what I was doing and thus would make it hard for someone else to maintain.

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions?

Comment: I have a regular expression when comparing the NON Month, Day, and Year portion of the mask. I originally tried this with the Month, Day, and Year portion too, but it took a lot longer, and what I was doing didn't seem so obvious. I've updated my question to show you what I was doing before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be to rewrite your pattern into [strftime/strptime pattern](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/) and test with those functions. I am using versions included in core [Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aPiece) module.

```
use Time::Piece;

test('12/31/2010' => 'MM-DD-YYYY');
test('12/31/2010' => 'DD/MM/YYYY');
test('12/31-11'   => 'MM/DD-YY');

sub test {
    my ($time, $mask) = @_;
    my $t = eval { Time::Piece->strptime($time, make_format_from($mask)) };
    print "String: $time  Mask: $mask  "
      . (defined $t ? "Pass: ".$t->ymd : "Fail"), "\n";
}

sub make_format_from {
    my $mask = shift;
    for($mask) {
        s/YYYY/%Y/;
        s/YY/%y/;
        s/MM/%m/;
        s/DD/%d/;
    }
    return $mask;
}
```

This code yields

```
String: 12/31/2010  Mask: MM-DD-YYYY  Fail
String: 12/31/2010  Mask: DD/MM/YYYY  Fail
String: 12/31-11  Mask: MM/DD-YY  Pass: 2011-12-31
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I can simply use the strptime format for my masks which is better documented than the mask format I was using anyway. No need for the make_format_from function. I checked the CPAN archive for something like this, but it can be difficult to find something there.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using some regular expressions in this code. Why not convert the user's mask into a pattern and use a regular expression to validate the input directly? Say,

```
$mask =~ s/YYYY/\\d{4}/;
# or:  $mask =~ s/YYYY/[12][0-9]{3}/
$mask =~ s/MM/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/;               # MM => 01 - 12
$mask =~ s/DD/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/;      # DD => 01 - 31
$mask =~ s/YY/\\d{2}/;                        # YY => 00 - 99
$mask = '^' . $mask . '$';
```

So for example, this would compile the user mask `MM-DD-YY` into the pattern 
`^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-\d{2}$`, which you could test with:

```
if ($input =~ qr/$mask/) {
    print "Input is valid\n";
} else {
    print "Input is invalid\n";
}
```

Comment: Both the mask and the string are user generated, so I can't say exactly what the mask will look like or the actual string will be. User #1 enters a *format* they require the date to be in and User #2 is the one who enters the date, and that date must match the format given by User #1. I was thinking of using Time::Format, but it doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by using regular expressions:

For `MM/DD-YY`:

`die "Wrong format" unless $date =~ /([01][0-9])\/([0-3][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])/;`

If it matches, the parentheses capture the different parts, and can be referred to as `$1`, `$2` etc.. Then use those variables for further testing, e.g. if month is between [1,12].

Btw., this pattern is not y2k compatible...

Comment: I am passing a mask and I am passing a string to validate the string against the mask. I need to do two things: One is to extract the Month, Day, and Year from the string via the mask, and the other is to compare the string against the mask to make sure they match. Your answer does neither of those.

Comment: @DavidW.: Sorry, I missed that the also the format must be user specified. However, I don't think this was particularly clear from your question.